# Creating result array from UNION ALL query

Tags: php, mysql, database, union

I am still learning php and I have to maintain a portion of my website.
I need to combine two database tables to show only the latest 10 articles from two databases.

I know I have to add something after
$articles = $this->db->query($query1 . ' UNION ALL ' . $query2);
to return the results, but I can't figure out the code.

```
$this->db->select("id,article_type,title,main_img1,open_date");
        $this->db->from('column');
        $this->db->where('open_flg', 1);
        $this->db->where('open_date <= NOW()');
        $this->db->where('(close_date >= NOW() OR close_date = \'0000-00-00 00:00:00\')');
        $query1 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
        $this->db->reset_query();
        
        $this->db->select("id,article_type,title,main_img1,open_date");
        $this->db->from('cases');
        $this->db->where('open_flg', 1);
        $this->db->where('open_date <= NOW()');
        $this->db->where('(close_date >= NOW() OR close_date = \'0000-00-00 00:00:00\')');
        $query2 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
        $this->db->reset_query();
            
        $articles = $this->db->query($query1 . ' UNION ALL ' . $query2);
        
        $query = $this->db->query($articles . 'ORDER BY open_date DESC  LIMIT 10 ');
        $data['article_posts'] = $query->result_array();
```

P.S.
The original code was only one database hence the following code worked fine:

```
$this->db->select("id,article_type,title,main_img1,open_date");
        $this->db->from('column');
        $this->db->where('open_flg', 1);
        $this->db->where('open_date <= NOW()');
        $this->db->where('(close_date >= NOW() OR close_date = \'0000-00-00 00:00:00\')');
        $articles = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

        $query = $this->db->query($articles . 'ORDER BY open_date DESC  LIMIT 10 ');
        $data['article_posts'] = $query->result_array();
```

If I replace the single database code for the UNION ALL one,
I get the following error:
Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to string

Comment: try just calling query once: `$query = $this->db->query($query1 . ' UNION ALL ' . $query2 . ' ORDER BY open_date DESC  LIMIT 10 ');`

Comment: @ysth Thank you so much! This worked. Could you please post it as an answer??

Answer (score 0):

Yes that error can be possible because $articles variable is an query object. need to convert $articles variable into string like done in case of query1 and query2.

before below line $articles variable need to convert into string first-

$query = $this->db->query($articles . 'ORDER BY open_date DESC  LIMIT 10 ');